# Cubic image converter?

Tags: image, video, projection, fisheye, cubic

I am looking for software (preferably free) that runs on either windows or osx that can take a list cubic images (broken into front, back, up, down, left, right) and turn them into a video. I am also looking for software to create fisheye projections from these images.

Have had a bit of a look around and can't seem to find anything that really suits my purposes. Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question and I was curious as to whether there might be a Gimp plugin for this.  I did not find one, but my search turned up this: http://www.clickheredesign.com.au/software/ I have not tried it but it appears to be what you are looking for.  You could also potentially roll your own in scheme or python script-fu for Gimp.

Comment: I have tried this one, however they don't allow you to save anything with the free version.